# Highcharts: aligning data labels on the same line in bar charts

Tags: highcharts

How could i achieve to align the data labels on the same vertical line in Highcharts bar charts as showned in the example below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set:

```
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    inside: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 390 //offset
                }
            }
        },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5aF54/1/

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to set the offset dynamically based on the bar length?

Comment: Only fixed value is possible to set. You can in `load` function get bar height (bar is the same as column chart, but inverted) and then call `series.update({ dataLabels: { x: newValue }});` to update position for dataLabels.

Comment: can u explain clearly that how to dynamically change the position based on the bar height

Comment: Sure, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5aF54/26/ (all labels: http://jsfiddle.net/5aF54/27/ )